How do we configure AWS API gateway to return the RateLimit headers?
I have created usage plan and API key to request rate limit. How do i configure the AWS API gateway to return bellow headers in the response ?
X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 99
X-RateLimit-Reset: 2016-10-12T11:00:00Z
